# Cannot log into admin account

Tags: login, lightdm

I saved a command that would hide the accounts other than the **admin** into the `lightdm` file and it chose to keep an "other" account for which I don't have the password.

I cannot open the terminal from the login so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a terminal by striking <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd>. Then you can make the changes you need there.

You can even restart the `lightdm` service afterward with

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Then re-enter your `lightdm` session by striking <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F7</kbd>

Comment: ok, I got the terminal going but do you know the commands in order to make the login for the accounts visible? should I only delete the last line I added?? thanks again!

Comment: Edit your post and put up the script you added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --hide-users false
```